# Proving existence of square roots

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

In Rudin's proof of the existence of square roots, he assumes for a contradiction that $y^n < x$ where $y = \sup\{t \in \mathbb{R} \mid t > 0, \; t^n < x\}$. He then asserts that there exists $h \in (0,1)$ with $h < \frac{x-y^n}{n(y+1)^{n-1}}$ so that $(y+h)^n < x$. I'm trying to understand exactly where he uses continuity of the function $f(u) = u^n$ and specifically which value of $\epsilon$ he choose. It's clear that $h$ is his $\delta$. From what I can tell, $x - y^n$ seems to be his $\epsilon$. Is this correct?

Comment: Using the supremum as the root implicitly uses both continuity and monotonicity, but it also bypasses any $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity (which if I recall correctly isn't even defined until the next chapter).  Why are you wanting to rephrase it in explicit terms of continuity?

Answer (score 1):

He didn't really need the concept of continuity to do what he did.

He has a number $y$ such that $y = \sup\{t\mid t^n<x\}$ and $y^n<x$. All he wants to do is to construct a number slightly bigger than $y$ but still satisfy the fact that the $n$th power of that number is still less than $x$.

Here is how he construct this slightly bigger number. He considers $y+h$ which is strictly greater than $y$ provided $h>0$. Clearly, $h$ can't be arbitrarily large if he wants $(y+h)^n<x$. So, he needs to come up with a condition for $h$ in terms of $y$ and $n$. Note that we only need to find one $h$ to complete the contradiction. Hence it suffices to restrict our attention to the values of $h$ that are less than one.

Note that in general, we have the equality
\begin{align}
a^n-b^n = (a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\ldots + ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})
\end{align}
this means that
\begin{align}
(y+h)^n-y^n = h((y+h)^{n-1}+(y+h)^{n-2}y+\ldots + y^{n-1})<h((y+1)^{n-1}+(y+1)^{n-1}+\ldots +(y+1)^{n-1}) = hn(y+1)^{n-1}.
\end{align}

Since we want to find $h$ such that $(y+h)^n<x$, then this is the same as wanting to find $h$ such that
\begin{align}
x-y^n>(y+h)^n-y^n.
\end{align}
In fact, it suffices to choose $h$ so that
\begin{align}
x-y^n>hn(y+1)^{n-1}
\end{align}
since
\begin{align}
x-y^n>hn(y+1)^{n-1}>(y+h)^n-y^n.
\end{align}
Then it is clear that the above inequality holds provided
\begin{align}
h<\frac{x-y^n}{n(y+1)^{n-1}}.
\end{align}